# Simple REST API server

Tags: python, api, twisted

This is a chunk of code I wrote for a job interview at some point - it is a remote key-value storage REST API supporting CRUD operations.

Maybe anyone has some feedback on this? It would be very helpful for me.

I did not attach the tests, since it might be a little bit too much code. You don't have to review both files - even commenting on just one can be extremely helpful.

## remotekvs.py

```
# -*- test-case-name: tests.remotekvs_test.RemoteKVSTest -*-

import json
import inspect

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site

from keyvaluestorage import KeyValueStorage


class RemoteKVSResource(Resource):
    """
    This is a Twisted Resource object used to serve requests for
    KeyValueStorage operations. It supports POST, GET, PUT and DELETE
    request methods and replies in JSON.
    """
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.kvs = KeyValueStorage()

    def render(self, request):
        operations = {
            'POST': 'create',
            'GET': 'read',
            'PUT': 'update',
            'DELETE': 'delete'}
        if request.method in operations.keys():
            response = {
                'success': True}
            try:
                operation = getattr(self.kvs, operations[request.method])
                args = {k: v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v
                        for k, v in request.args.items()}
                result = operation(**(args))
                if result is not None:
                    response['result'] = result
            except (TypeError, KeyValueStorage.KeyAlreadyExistsError,
                    KeyValueStorage.InvalidKeyError), exception:
                response['success'] = False
                response['error'] = exception.__class__.__name__
                if isinstance(exception, TypeError):
                    response['error_message'] = (
                        "Valid request parameters: %s." % (
                            ', '.join(inspect.getargspec(operation)[0][1:])))
                else:
                    response['error_message'] = str(exception)
        else:
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'error': 'InvalidRequestMethod',
                'error_message': (
                    "Valid request methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE.")}
        return json.dumps(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover
    site = Site(RemoteKVSResource())
    reactor.listenTCP(2048, site)
    reactor.run()
```

## keyvaluestorage.py

```
# -*- test-case-name: tests.keyvaluestorage_test.KeyValueStorageTest -*-


class KeyValueStorage(object):
    """The most basic key-value storage, supports all 4 CRUD operations."""

    class KeyAlreadyExistsError(Exception):
        """Key you are trying to create already exists in the database."""

    class InvalidKeyError(Exception):
        """Key you are trying to access does not exist in the database."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.storage = {}

    def create(self, key, value):
        if key in self.storage.keys():
            raise self.KeyAlreadyExistsError(
                ("Key already exists. KeyValueStorage does not allow "
                 "duplicate keys."))
        self.storage[key] = value

    def read(self, key):
        try:
            return self.storage[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise self.InvalidKeyError(
                "Key does not exist. You can not read by a nonexistent key.")

    def update(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.storage.keys():
            raise self.InvalidKeyError(
                "Key does not exist. You can not update by a nonexistent key.")
        self.storage[key] = value

    def delete(self, key):
        try:
            del self.storage[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise self.InvalidKeyError(
                "Key does not exist. You can not delete by a nonexistent key.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write the error handling this way:

```
def render(self, request):
    operations = {
        'POST': 'create',
        'GET': 'read',
        'PUT': 'update',
        'DELETE': 'delete',
    }
    if request.method not in operations:
        response = {
            'success': False,
            'error': 'InvalidRequestMethod',
            'error_message': ("Valid request methods: %s" % (', '.join(operations.keys()))),
        }
        request.setResponseCode(http.NOT_ALLOWED)
    else:
        response = {'success': True}
        ...
    return json.dumps(response)
```

Note the changes:

- Since the error handler is simpler than the main processing code, put it first to get it out of the way.
- `if request.method not in operations` reads better than `if request.method not in operations.keys()` and might be slightly more efficient.
- Reuse `operations.keys()` for the error message.
- Set [HTTP status 405 ("Method Not Allowed")](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6).  (The constant is in `twisted.web.http`.)

In `KeyValueStorage`, I suggest raising the standard `KeyError` instead of making your own exception classes.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with all of the above. The fact that `k in dict.keys()` is O(n), while `k in dict` is O(1) have never crossed my mind.